# 'Raw-send' using PHPmailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I need to write a PHP script that can insert one (or more) additional header, and re-send it to another email address.

How would I do that using PHPmailer? I can't seem to find how to do a 'raw send' of email message (with additional headers inserted already).

Or, if PHPmailer can't do that, how do you recommend I do what I want?

Comment: PHPMailer seems to have a `$CustomHeader` variable. Check out your copy to see how exactly it is named

Answer (score 1):

After spelunking around, I decided to just use 'fsockopen' and adapt [this PHP snippet](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/36108-send-emails-using-php-smtp-direct/) (lots of bugs there).

Thanks for everyone commenting!